# $f: B \to C$ injective $\implies \exists \hat f:A\subset B \to C$ injective.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$f: B \to C$ injective $\implies \exists \hat f:A\subset B \to C$ injective.

I've stumbled with a problem where using this would trivialize it. This statement appears to be pretty obvious to me, so trivial that a proof escapes my imagination. How can this be proved?

Comment: Just let $\hat{f}$ be the restriction of $f$ to $A$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Let $\hat{f}: A \to C$, where $\hat{f}(a)=f(a) \forall a \in A$.

Comment: But how can you say $\hat f=f$ if they have different domains?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:B \to C$ be injective, and let $A \subseteq B$ be any subset.  Then we can define $\hat{f}: A \to C$ to simply just be $\hat{f} = f|_A$, where $f|_A(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in A$, and is undefined otherwise.  Notice that if $x,y \in A$ then $\hat{f}(x) = \hat{f}(y)$ means that $f(x) = f(y)$, but since $f$ is injective everywhere in $B$ (including $A$) we must have that $x=y$.  Therefore $\hat{f}$ is injective.

Comment: You might want to write the explicit definition of the restricted function.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I edited my post somewhat to make it clearer.  Do you have another suggestion in mind?

Comment: Nothing that a comment won't do. If $f\subseteq B\times C$, then $f|_A=f\cap A\times C$.